# Excel - edit template text box

Tags: excel

Excel Version: 2016

If I open a Microsoft excel template, for example, house cleaning checklist, there are some default text boxes that appear.

[image]

How can I delete or edit these text boxes?  They are not comments for the cell and nothing happens when I right click on them.  There is nothing in the macro or the VB portion of the 'Developer' tab.

The only thing I can do is move the text box.

Answer (score 0):

It was an 'Input Message'.

Select the cell that has the message text box.  Next, click on the 'Data' tab, under the 'Data Tools' section, click on 'Data Validation' then 'Data Validation...'
[image]

From there, click on 'Input Message' and either uncheck 'Show input message when cell is selected' or update the message.

[image]